# PHP Get int value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

so I've been trying to get result from db as an integer;
I only store one row of information, therefore i select by only one value. How do I convert my result to integer? i have also tried $dbnum_rows = (int) but it also didn't help ;/

```
$query1 = "SELECT num_rows FROM config";
$dbnum_rows = $mysqli->query($query1);
$dbnum_rows = intval($dbnum_rows);

$query2 = "SELECT num_cols FROM config";
$dbnum_cols = $mysqli->query($query2);
$dbnum_cols = intval($dbnum_cols);
```

Comment: "my result" means?

Comment: it means object that i got from database as a result. how do i convert ($mysqli->query($query1); as int type since I use it in my functions as integer later on

Comment: why this do that?

Answer (score 0):

The result of an `execute` call is a result object. You can't just beat it over the head with `intval` and expect anything meaningful to come out. Instead, do this:

```
$numbers = array();
while($row = $dbnum_cols->fetch_array())
{
  $rows[] = intval($row[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are coming from another language where parsing or casting data types is common. Although this practice does exist in php as of php7, it is often not required as data types are not explicitly defined by the developer but rather determined by php at runtime. for example, in php:

```
$a = "1";      // this is a string
$b = 2;        // This is an int

$x = $a + $b;  // $c = 3;
```

So as stated by tadman, your results are an object through which you need to iterate, and get the first index `$row[0]` which can readily be treated as an integer without `intval()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you save the field in the database how a varchar, you need cast in PHP using something like this:

```
(int)str_replace(' ', '', $b);
```

Remember you should quit all spaces.

Comment: That would work if the value was even close to being what was expected, but it's not.